# Cubic Bezier curve mapping to a segment of a curve that is y = sin(fx)

Tags: trigonometry, bezier-curve

I've seen [1] [Getting the most accurate bezier curve that plots a sine wave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235124/getting-the-most-accurate-bezier-curve-that-plots-a-sine-wave/4235337#4235337)

and [2] [Can a rational Bézier curve take exactly the same shape as a part of the sine function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/can-a-rational-b%c3%a9zier-curve-take-exactly-the-same-shape-as-a-part-of-the-sine-fu)

but neither actually answer my question which is...

I have a curve that is $y = \sin(f(x))$.

I am only interested in addressing a part of that curve where $x$ is between $x_0$ and $x_3$. The range for x is constrained such that $|x_3-x_0| \le  \pi$.
[For example I only need to fit a Bezier curve to $y$ between $x = \pi/6$ and $\pi/4$]

I can calculate the tangents at $P_0$ (i.e. at ${x_0,y_0}$) and $P_3$ (${x_3, y_3}$)

I am looking for a method to calculate Bezier control points $P_1$ and $P_2$ where:

- symmetry is not a given (as was assumed in [1])
- an approximation is adequate ([2] demonstrates that there is no exact fit)

(It isn't clear to me if the control points $P_1$ and $P_2$ *must* lie on the tangents; but it would be good if there is a solution where they do.)

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve readability.

Comment: Do you want the Bézier curve to be in the form $y=f(x)$, or in parametric form: $x=f(t), y=g(t)$?

Comment: Does the Bézier curve need to be cubic (degree 3), or can we use any degree we like?

Comment: How will you judge the quality of the approximation? In other words, what measure of error do you want to minimize?

Comment: Can you tell us anything about your function $f$? For example, is it continuous, differentiable, monotone?

Comment: Hi @bubba. f(x) is continuous (typically some linear function to give the angle). Measure of error - not bothered - visually "ok". Must be cubic bezier.  I'm looking to calculate $P_1$ and $P_2$ - so I imagine $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$ would be better?